# Closed and open subsets of Spec(R)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose we are given a commutative ring with unit $R$ and an ideal $I \subseteq R$. I wondered if then the following is true:
$$
V(I) \text{ is open in Spec}(R) \Leftrightarrow I = I^2.
$$
I know that one should make further assumptions, maybe one should take $R$ to be noetherian or at least $I$ to be finitely generated. In the latter case the implication $\Leftarrow$ follows easily from Nakayama's lemma. Concerning the other implication: I am not sure whether this is true or which additional assumptions on $R$ and $I$ one would have to make. I would be glad to hear other opinions on this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V(I)$ is open when its complement is closed, i.e. equals $V(J)$ for some ideal $J$.  $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is the disjoint union of $V(I)$ and $V(J)$ exactly when $I+J=R$, and $I\cap J\subset\sqrt{0}$.

Assuming that $R$ is reduced (or, weaker, that $I$ is), we have $I\cap J = 0$, so $R \cong I \oplus J$.  In particular, $I^2 = I$.*

On the other hand, if $R$ is not reduced, there may be trouble.  For example, if $R=\mathbb{Z}/4$, $I=(2)$, then $V(I)=\operatorname{Spec} R$ is certainly open, but $I^2 = 0 \neq I$.

---

* To see this concretely: write $1 = a + b$, with $a\in I$, $b\in J$.  Then, for any $x\in I$, we have $x = ax + bx = ax \in I^2$.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.